# VirtualBox dynamic disk not expanding to Virtual Size

Tags: virtualbox, 12.04, vdi

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on VirtualBox 4.2.4 in a Dynamic VDI disk with the limit set to 8gb on a real ext4 partition with more than 40gb of empty room available. However, the VDI it does not expand to the limit. 8gb is more than enough for what I want to do.

How do I make the rest of the space available?  Available space in / and .home is 41kb.

[image: vm]

[image: vdi]

Comment: Is this a bug then?

Comment: My hack-ish solution was to just add another virtual drive. BTW I didn't test this myself, but [this page](http://www.gitshah.com/2013/05/how-to-fix-out-of-space-problem-for.html) suggests that the issue is caused by the fact that the swap partition is placed after the main partition. I'll try rearranging partitions next time I'm installing ubuntu guest and post a follow-up.

Comment: You probably made a partition that is too small, explaining the full disk.

Answer (score 4):

**VirtualBox Dynamic Disk Not Utilizing Available Free Disk Space to Grow Partition Automatically**

This post was written for Ubuntu Server 18.04 Guest OS running on Virtualbox 6.1.6.

I believe that the correct description to this problem should be something along the lines of this:

*"Although a 32GB dynamic disk was created, the OS partition hit a "disk full" message at around 4GB and wasn't able to automatically increase its size by utilizing the "free" 28GB from the 32GB dynamic disk."*

If this is the problem you encountered, and you had setup the Guest OS using Ubuntu Linux and LVM (and EXT4 filesystem), then the solution to this problem is to use **lvextend** and **resize2fs** commands. See my solution and description below:

Start up the VM and login. Once in, open up a terminal.

1. Display information about **allocated** disk storage:

   $ `df -h`

   Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   udev                               966M     0  966M   0% /dev
   tmpfs                              200M  1.1M  199M   1% /run
   **/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  2.9G  835M  78% /**
   tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   /dev/loop0                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
   /dev/loop1                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
   /dev/sda2                          976M  212M  697M  24% /boot
   tmpfs                              200M     0  200M   0%  /run/user/1000

The output shows the root partition (/) has a size of 3.9G and that 2.9G (78%) is used.

2. Display information on block devices:

   $ `lsblk`

   NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   loop0                       7:0    0 96.5M  1 loop /snap/core/9436
   loop1                       7:1    0   97M  1 loop /snap/core/9665
   sda                         8:0    0   32G  0 disk
   ├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
   ├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
   └─sda3                      8:3    0   31G  0 part
   **└─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    4G  0 lvm  /**
   sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

The output shows that block device sda has a physical size of 32GB. It contains 3 partitions (sda1, sda2 and sda3). The root partition (/) mounted on the logical volume of sda3 only has 4GB allocated storage. This means that there is still approximately 27GB of **unallocated (free)** storage that we can use to grow the LVM's logical volume.

3. Display filesystem information on the block devices:

   $ `lsblk --fs`

   NAME    FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
   loop0   squashfs                                                 /snap/core/9436
   loop1   squashfs                                                 /snap/core/9665
   sda
   ├─sda1
   ├─sda2  ext4              7cafee4a-d300-4b17-957d-c822c73882fc   /boot
   └─sda3  LVM2_member       GwPZus-EMpD-BgZw-e1Nx-Fd9J-LLeN-XnbvEE
   └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
   **ext4**              dcc015b4-b6b8-4e05-9a18-93c263cc05ed   /
   sr0

   The output shows that filesystem of the lvm root partition is ext4.
4. Display information about physical volume:

   $ `sudo pvs`

   PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
   /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <31.00g <27.00g

   $ `sudo pvdisplay`

   --- Physical volume ---
   PV Name               /dev/sda3
   VG Name               ubuntu-vg
   PV Size               <31.00 GiB / not usable 0
   Allocatable           yes
   PE Size               4.00 MiB
   Total PE              7935
   Free PE               6911
   Allocated PE          1024
   PV UUID               GwPZus-EMpD-BgZw-e1Nx-Fd9J-LLeN-XnbvEE

   The output provides another perspective on the allocated / unallocated space on LVM PV sda3.
5. Display information about volume group:

   $ `sudo vgs`

   VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
   ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <31.00g <27.00g

   $ `sudo vgdisplay`

   --- Volume group ---
   VG Name               ubuntu-vg
   System ID
   Format                lvm2
   Metadata Areas        1
   Metadata Sequence No  2
   VG Access             read/write
   VG Status             resizable
   MAX LV                0
   Cur LV                1
   Open LV               1
   Max PV                0
   Cur PV                1
   Act PV                1
   VG Size               <31.00 GiB
   PE Size               4.00 MiB
   Total PE              7935
   Alloc PE / Size       1024 / 4.00 GiB
   Free  PE / Size       6911 / <27.00 GiB
   VG UUID               vBmSeb-VWR8-7A8n-CBSa-UnKd-FmJG-LTtMUG

   The output shows that the VG size is the same as the PV size (31GB), and that it has 27GB of unallocated free storage to grow the logical volume.
6. Display information about the logical volume:

   $ `sudo lvs`

   LV        VG        Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
   ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 4.00g

   $ `sudo lvdisplay`

   --- Logical volume ---
   LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
   LV Name                ubuntu-lv
   VG Name                ubuntu-vg
   LV UUID                pnvBcu-FnfT-c3RY-cYCE-AuMX-f833-57WvYi
   LV Write Access        read/write
   LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2020-07-01 00:00:58 +0000
   LV Status              available
   #open                 1
   LV Size                4.00 GiB
   Current LE             1024
   Segments               1
   Allocation             inherit
   Read ahead sectors     auto
   -currently set to     256
   Block device           253:0

   The output shows that the LV size is 4GB. Since the VG size is 31GB, we can grow the LV by another 27GB.

7a. To grow the logical volume (ubuntu-lv) by using 50% (13GB) of the free unallocated space, first do:

```
$ sudo lvextend -l+50%free /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 4.00 GiB (1024 extents) to 17.50 GiB (4480 extents).
Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.


The output shows that the logical volume has grown from 4GB to 17.5GB (approximately 13GB).
```

7b. Finally, to let the EXT4 filesystem become aware of the expanded storage, run command:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 3
The filesystem on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv is now 4587520 (4k) blocks long.
```

8. Display information about **allocated** disk storage again to check the new disk storage space:

   $ `df -h`

   Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   udev                               966M     0  966M   0% /dev
   tmpfs                              200M  1.1M  199M   1% /run
   **/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   18G  2.9G   14G  18% /**
   tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   tmpfs                              997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   /dev/loop0                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
   /dev/loop1                          97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9665
   /dev/sda2                          976M  212M  697M  24% /boot
   tmpfs                              200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000

   The output shows that the size of the logical volume has now grown to 18GB (from its earlier 4GB)

Comment: thank you, Part 7b) was the missing link in my case. EXT4 wasn't aware of the new space.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my VirtualBox machine by setting the path on Windows 7 host machine to include the VirtualBox install directory (Steps):

1. click start button
2. Right click computer
3. Click Properties
4. Click Advanced System Settings
5. On [Advanced] tab click [Environment Variables] button
6. Under System Variables, scroll down to path and click [Edit]
7. Add everything in quotes to end of line ";C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
8. Click [Ok]

Next move to the directory of the VirtualBox Disk (under username\VirtualBox VMs)
taken from (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=52351)

1. open cmd and move to the VirtualBox drive
2. enter this command: VBoxManage showhdinfo
3. Take note of the UUID of the disk.
4. enter this command: VBoxManage modifyhd UUID_of_the_VDI_disk --resize 80000 (this makes the disk 80 gigs, adjust to the size you want)

**IMPORTANT STEPS START HERE:**
Next boot the Virtual machine on LiveCD (Install disk)
(taken from [Extending Ubuntu Partition size with the unallocated space (swap is between these two)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300103/extending-ubuntu-partition-size-with-the-unallocated-space-swap-is-between-thes))

I can't stress this enough:

It is highly recommended to backup any important files before doing resize/move/extend operations.

The way to do it, is by deleting the swap partition, extend the partition that you want, and then re-create the swap partition.

Swap partition can only be deleted after swap is turned off:

SWAP off: sudo /sbin/swapoff -a SWAP on: sudo /sbin/swapon -a

The steps:

1. Boot from the Ubuntu LiveCD
2. Open terminal, and turn swap off
3. Install GParted
4. Extend the partiton that you want, but leave space for swap
5. commit the changes
6. create swap partition
7. turn swap on

Note: If your swap is not your primary hard drive, then see SwapFaq on how to activate the swap partition

It is highly recommended to backup any important files before doing resize/move/extend operations.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu 15.04 running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 in a Virtual Machine. It seems that despite it being 'Dynamically allocated storage' VirtuaBox wasn't increasing it and I was down to my last 100MB and it wouldn't let me update via Software Updates. The solution was to perform the update via the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This seemed to force VirtualBox to create the additional storage, it jumped up to 500MB free as soon as the update started.

Comment: That's really odd. I ran `dpkg -i` and `apt-get update` got a message about being out of space, but `apt-get upgrade` worked on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp` is going to be a `tmpfs` - i.e. a filesystem stored in RAM. So unless you assigned you have ~800MB free RAM in your VM, it isn't going to be enough to hold the ISO.

This is probably not what you intended: just save the ISO in a 'real' directory (e.g. `/home/<username>`) and it should work just fine.

Comment: So if I am trying to load 1+GB of files into MongoDB and the VM memory is set to 1024 is it likely that I would be running into the same issue?

Comment: Where is the file stored? If it's disk-backed, then no - MongoDB should read the file in chunks and load it rather than loading the entire file at once. By storing your ISO in `/tmp`, you're forcing the OS to store the entire ISO in memory.

Comment: dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb      I'm getting the computer is running out of disk space message from the OS. Apparently, my image was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be related to the growth of your virtual disk as you should have an error message from VirtualBox telling you that it can't allocate more disk space for your virtual disk.

Some ideas:

- Did you use a special partitionning scheme in your VM?
- What's the result of `df -h` in your VM?
- You may use `baobab` to search what consumes all your `/` space.

Comment: +1 for baobab. Although it did not tell me why the vdi won't grow it's going to be useful in the future.

Comment: Thanks. From what I can tell, your vdi don't grow because the OS inside don't need it to grow. I mean, surely your `/tmp` or even `/` filesystem is full in your VM. The filesystem won't expand by itself. What `df -h` tells you?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a shared folder, it may be a solution to your problem.

1. From VirtualBox enter your VM settings > shared folders and add a new one; choose the path in your host machine name it `FOLDER_NAME` and check `Auto mount` and `make permanent`.
2. Install Guest additions; look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) to see how
3. Make a folder on your guest VM to point to the folder created on the host, just create a new folder, for example `/home/"your_user_name"/shared`
4. Mmount the shared folder: `sudo mount -t vboxsf  "FOLDER_NAME" /home/"your_user_name"/shared`
5. To make the mount automatic, add `mount -t vboxsf  "FOLDER_NAME" /home/"your_user_name"/shared" to the end of "/etc/rc.local" before "exit 0"`

Comment: Can you please describe how to do that to make this a [good answer worth keeping](/help/how-to-answer)?

Comment: I put details on the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this easy solution:
In your Terminal type this command

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "path-of-your-disk" --resize 20000
```

You can find the path of your disk under the configuration of your VM / storage / yourVM.vbi (path on the right)

Comment: He probably made an partition in the VM, thus resizing the disk has only an influence on the host.

Comment: So it's not about the hypervisor ! he should modify the partition inside the VM...!!

Comment: That is indeed what I meant.