# Adding Additional HDD to Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: server, partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive, samba

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server on Oracle VM VirtualBox as I'm trying to understand the deployment to be ready to deploy it in a real network.

Here is the situation. Currently, I have assigned a 8GB HDD to the VM which I use for the system. Now, I want to add another HDD, say 12GB, to be used with Samba for storing files to be shared among multiple users.

What I need to be able to do is:

1. Add a new 12GB HDD to the VM
2. Link the newly added HDD to the system
3. Mount it as /srv/share/ which will be used with the Samba

What I also need to know, is the process the same for a real hardware?

The base HDD is 500GB and the secondary is 1TB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are minimum steps to create and attach a new virtual hard drive to an existing virtual machine:

#### In the host:

1. Create a virtual hard drive

   ```
   VBoxManage VBoxManage createhd --filename <path/to/name.vdi> --size <in MB>
   ```
2. Attach this drive to the VM

   ```
   VBoxManage storageattach "<VM name" --storagectl SATA-Controller --port <number> --type hdd --medium </path/to/name.vdi>
   ```
3. Boot the virtual machine

Alternatively we may also just add a new partition to an already attached exisiting virtual drive by [increasing it's size](https://askubuntu.com/a/248204/3940) which then needs to be partitioned too.

#### In the guest:

4. Partition the new drive

   You may want to find out the device decriptor of the new drive with `sudo fdisk l` first.

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/<sdx> ## run parted on device sdx
   (parted) mklabel msdos ## create a msdos partition
   (parted) mkpart primary ext4 1MiB 100% ## create primary ext4 partition using whole disk
   (parted) quit
   ```
5. Format the new partition

   ```
   sudo mkfs -t ext4 </dev/sdX1>
   ```
6. Mount this partition

   ```
   sudo mount <options> /dev/sdx1 <mountpoint>
   ```
7. If mounting in 4. worked then optionally put an entry in `/etc/fstab` for mounting on boot:

   ```
   <UUID>   <mountpoint>   ext4    <options>    0    2
   ```

   The `<UUID>` can be read from `sudo blkid`, `<options>` as for `mount`.

All steps can of course also be performed from a GUI. For steps 1. to 3. this would be the Virtual Box Manager in the host. For steps 4. to 5. it would be `gparted` in the guest (e.g. by temporarily booting to a live Ubuntu). Manual mounting needs a terminal, editing fstab can be done with any editor.

For more details on creating virtual hard drives also see the [Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-createvdi).

Comment: Thank you Takkat for the guidance .. Got couple of points I need to check/confirm .. 1) The same guide will work normally with a real machine, except that steps 1-3 will be installing another HDD, right? 2) After finishing the above, on the reboot, the box hangs until I skip the mount of the new partition .. I feel I'm missing something here

Comment: @sikas: your ftsab entry may have an issue... any errors on mounting manually (resp. `sudo mount -a`)?

Comment: nope, `sudo mount -a` works fine ...

Comment: well, actually, I had an issue with the type .. it was `ext` instead of `ext4` .. corrected that and worked fine ..

Comment: can you check point 1, in my first comment, and advise on it?

Comment: yeah, partitioning with `parted` and mounting is the same on bare metal.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable using the CLI you can also partition with booting a graphical live system to use `gparted`.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Server, so I have to use CLI only .. I can deal with it, but sometimes I miss-type :(