# Why is my Ubuntu disk on virtualbox (host Windows 7) only 6 GB?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 14 on Windows 7 x64 VirtualBox. I set the vdi disk size to fixed size 10 GB. The settings say: virtual 10GB and actual 10GB. But when I start Ubuntu, it indicates only 6.3 GB. Basically I ran out of disk space directly after installing the OS...

Does anyone know how to set virtualbox disk space to a larger size?

Comment: For the lack of info, I can only guess that 6.3GB is the root partition, and the rest might be allocated to swap. There are lots of howtos for virtual box, just search. Also, consider allocating about 25GB instead of 10. http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

At the time you create your virtual machine you were asked to create virtual hard drive (VDI) to hold your new OS.

Choose a size large enough to not run out of space and up to max. 2 TB. If you had created a dynamically growing disk (this is default) the physical space used on your host will only be used to the actually need, but never exceeding the limit you gave here (e.g. 50 GB):

[image]

On a default installation Ubuntu will create a partition holding the OS and your data (`/`) plus a `/swap` partition. Swap size depends on RAM (you are allowed to assign all your phsyical RAM but it is better to leave some for the host). So depending on your virtual memory size the swap partition will add to the virtual hard drive space needed.

In case you do not want to use a swap you need to perform a custom install of Ubuntu ("do someting else").

It is [possible to grow the virtual disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248189/why-does-virtualbox-virtual-disk-not-grow-automatically) after installation but there is more involved than just a command. You may at present be much faster you just installed Ubuntu again, but on a much bigger virtual drive.