# Enlarging a fixed size virtualbox disk with Ubuntu as host, Windows as guest

Tags: virtualbox

I have successfully installed Windows 7 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and transferred data.  I now realise that 40Gb (fixed) is not big enough and want to make the size 100Gb (fixed).  Although widely reported there are a number of issues to understand before I attempt the change.  I do not want to lose the data already transferred.
I have already cloned the 40Gb machine and all works ok but I understood wrongly that this would clone into a dynamic format which I could then change to 100Gb.  I do not trust the term 'variant Standard' to mean variant Dynamic after a previous discussion on SE.
So the question is how to safely increase the size of a VirtualBox machine which has a fixed format under Ubuntu 16.04.
The detailed questions are:-

1. Can I use variant Standard to create a dynamic format if I have to go through this route?
2. Is this the safest way to increase the fixed size from 40Gb to a fixed size of 100Gb?

Comment: Depending on what you want to archieve it could be enough just adding an additional virtual hard drive to that VM. And than use it within the virtual Windows as additional disk space where to install programs and store data. No need to resize the installation harddrive of the VM.

Comment: Many thanks.  I don't really want to go that route - or make it dual boot.  I only use Windows for  a few programs now - those that won't run in Linux or Mac.  If I can get an answer to the 'variant Standard'/Dynamic question I am happy to try anything.  I can't afford to lose the existing data - hence the nervousness about trying different things.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the key answer I need is the one about removing a cloned machine and all its contents - not as in my previous comment.  I could then add a new VM which has the right size - and then use dd?

Comment: I have edited the question relating to the 'Remove' function (see my comment above) - have established that the old VM is not affected.

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/248204/3940

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It looks as if the only way to increase the size of a fixed sized VM is to create a new one and clone the contents from the old one.