# Resizing Ubuntu Virtualbox vdi from a Windows7 host does not take effect

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, vdi

**I created a .vdi with fixed disk size and later resized the disk size and attached to my Linux VM. But still my VM is not updated with the resized disk**

Initially i got an error during the resize “Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!” , maybe because I was trying to resize a fixed size disk

So I first created a clone of the existing virtual hard drive via Command Prompt, as it creates "dynamically allocated virtual hard drive" so that I can resize it without any errors

[image]

Then resized the cloned vdi to 40GB:
[image]

Then attached my resized vdi to VirtualBox and removed my old vdi: 
[image]

I see that my disk size is resized here on the GUI.

But now when I run my VM, I still see that my disk size remains the same and not updated.

[image]

Any inputs on how I can update my VM with the resized disk will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Did you also [partition and format](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248189/why-does-virtualbox-virtual-disk-not-grow-automatically) the disk after growing?

Comment: Initially i didn't. Was able to resolve it after partitioning using GParted. I had to add the new extended "un-allocated" space to my disk

Answer (score 0):

I used GParted to modify the Linux native partition. I followed [Use GParted to increase disk size of a Linux native partition](https://www.rootusers.com/use-gparted-to-increase-disk-size-of-a-linux-native-partition/).