# ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 dual partition. Extending ubuntu memory

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, gparted

Previously, I have installed Windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04  as dual boot on my 320 GB laptop.
I have three partitions.
200 GB - Window's 7 is installed in it.
100 GB - NTFS partition its name is (new volume)where currently I am storing movies/music etc.
20 GB - Ubuntu 12.04.

I can access 100 GB (new volume) both in windows and ubuntu 12.04.

I am running out of ubuntu memory. How can I extend/increase it as I have 100 GB(unused) memory ? 
can I make use of that and make my ubuntu 120 GB ? What should I be doing?

I have installed gparted but it cannot extend my 20 GB ubuntu memory to 120 GB I guess.

Comment: the use of the word memory is a bit confusing since it mostly is used to refer to RAM memory, storage or storage space is more commonly used for space on the harddisc

Comment: my bad. I meant storage space on harddisc.

Comment: Make sure that the partitions are next to each other, and no partition is in between, like swap.  If there is then take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300103/extending-ubuntu-partition-size-with-the-unallocated-space-swap-is-between-thes/300193#300193).

Answer (score 0):

to resize a partition wit gparted you need to unmount the partition, and since Ubuntu is running you cannot unmount it. the solution is to use a live cd or usb, open gparted there. than you first shrink your windows partition and afterward add the than unallocated space to your Ubuntu partition. be very careful though, you are messing with all the storage on your computer so first make a backup of both your windows and Ubuntu files!

Comment: Thank you. Can I know what is success percentage of above method ? I mean What is the success % of being able to enhance the ubuntu storage without messing it up?

Comment: as long as you leave enough space for windows and a bit more you should be good to go. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions) is a good read to read trough. After you resize and boot into windows you will get an error because the disc space is not correct, and you need to allow it to scan the disc or something.