# Formatting ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I had dual boot with windows and ubuntu for a long time now. Today I decided to uninstall windows and format ubuntu.

The first thing I did was remove the partion where the windows OS was installed.
So far so good.

Secondly, I created a new backup partion with all the files I needed from both OS.

Now my HD has 4 partions.
One with ubuntu installed
One with my backup files
One 200GB which is empty
and a 80GB one to install my brand new ubuntu.

Then I downloaded ubuntu minimal install and bruned it to a dvd.

When I try to boot from dvd nothing happens. The GRUB still comes up(even though the only option is ubuntu).

How should I proceed?

All I want to do is:

Install ubuntu 13.04 minimal.
Don't overwrite my backup partion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to use a different release as 13.04 has already reached it's End Of Life in April. 13.10 support ends in July (much better release in my opinion) 12.04 (LTS) is still good for quite some time and 14.04 (LTS) just came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case best solution would be extending existing partition (probably `/dev/sda2`) to whole disk. [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions), [Extending Ubuntu partition...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300103/extending-ubuntu-partition-size-with-the-unallocated-space-swap-is-between-thes).

If you really want to reinstall partition you have to enter to boot menu (probably by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> or other key), and select your DVD drive from device list. This action will boot a DVD.

If you want to boot from DVD device first (before other devices) all time, read about BIOS settings for your BIOS vendor.